# my arithmetic expression doesnt work in a CMD FOR loop

Tags: for-loop, cmd, arithmetic-expressions

I want to generate a random number in a For Loop like that (part of it):

```
FOR /F "delims=, eol=; tokens=1,2" %%a in (DATA.TXT) DO (   
    SET min=10000
    SET max=99999
    SET /a passwort=!min!+(!max!-!min!+1)*%random%/32768
)
```

Unfortunately, it returns this error:

> "*[randomly generated number]/32768" cannot be processed syntactically at this point.

Comment: OP has a specific error which IMHO is not handled in [How to use random in BATCH script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5777400)

Answer (score 2):

- It doesn't work because the set /a command isn't double quoted and
  the (code block) ends prematurely with the unescaped closing
  parentheses in the formula.
- Otherwise the formula has the flaw that it could generate negative
  numbers due to multiplying first
  (set /a is limited to signed 32bit
  integer math).
- Also inside a (code block) it needs to be `!random!` while all the
  other variables don't need `%/!` for expansion (special to set /A)
- without further precautions a number password in this range isn't very secure,
  but you can use random numbers repeatedly to generate a password of arbitrary length from a set of characters like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49954976/6811411)

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\10\SO_51271717.cmd
@Echo off & SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

SET /A "min=10000,max=99999,range=max-min+1"

FOR /F "delims=, eol=; tokens=1,2" %%a in (DATA.TXT) DO (   
    SET /a "passwort=min + range / 32768* !random! "
    Echo passwort=!passwort!
)
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\07\10\SO_51271717.cmd
passwort=10528
passwort=56868
passwort=34042
passwort=40878
passwort=32590
passwort=47396
passwort=51676
passwort=66530
passwort=40106
passwort=56218
```